# No inserta los campos en Mysql desde PHP

Tags: php

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IP8a9.jpg)Hola tengo un problema al insertar datos desde php a mysql. Creo la conexión y hago la inserción, No sé si es la base de datos. Estoy trabajando con WAMP.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Manuel, te recomiendo visitar [ask] para mejorar un poco tu pregunta. Al menos podrias explicar que estas haciendo y donde crees que esta el error.

Comment: Hola, una disculpa es primera ves que publico aqui, listo ya agregue el comentario saludos

Comment: Mira, no estoy 100% seguro (por eso no publico la respuesta), pero creo que para usar arreglos asociativos en PHP, el indice debe ser un string (que es el nombre del elemento del arreglo). Te das cuenta  que en tu "if" si tienes la referencia al arreglo POST bien hecha, por ejemplo: $_POST['Diabetes'], ves como le has puesto comillas simples dentro? Ahora bien, en las consultas tienes, por ejemplo: $_POST[Diabetes], sin las comillas, ves? Creo que ese es el problema. Tambien te recomiendo chequear doble que todos los nombres de los campos de las tablas esten bien escritos en las consultas.

Comment: y tambien, mira sobre inyecciones SQL.. tu codigo es propenso a eso...

Comment: Hola gracias por sus respuestas @Kenny  mira lo chistoso es que asi como esta me guarda en algunas tablas y en otras no,  voy a poner la comilla a todos mis POST esperando que eso sea el problema si verifique como lo estoy haciendo en brackets al seleccionar un campo remarca el otro igual.

Comment: Puede ser, por eso te digo que no estoy 100% seguro. Y tambien no hay que fiarse 100% de los IDE o super editores, a veces no lo hacen todo bien. Espero y se arregle.

Comment: Si tienes razón los IDE a veces se equivocan igual estoy verificando de uno en uno a ver si tengo algún error pero la verdad no sé qué pasa ya tengo 1 día buscando ese error que no sé qué puede ser espero que alguien más me pueda ayudar gracias por tu respuesta  @Kenny

Answer (score 0):

que tal. en mi caso yo utilizo PDO.

para hacer la insercion.
Este es un ejemplo.

```
<?php
    include_once "conexion.php";
    if(isset($_POST)){
        if(isset($_POST['name']) && 
           isset($_POST['last_name']) && 
           isset($_POST['email']) && 
           isset($_POST['password'])){
                $nombre = $_POST['name'];
                $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
                $email = $_POST['email'];
                $password = $_POST['password'];

                //Ejecutar una sentencia preparada vinculando varialbes de PHP 

                $gsent = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO users (name, last_name, email, password)
                                        VALUES (:name,:last_name,:email,:password)');
                $gsent->bindParam(':name', $nombre, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $gsent->bindParam(':last_name', $last_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $gsent->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $gsent->bindParam(':password', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $state= $gsent->execute();
                if($state){
                    echo 'Datos ingresados';
                }
                else{
                    echo 'Datos NO Ingresados';
                }
                $pdo= null;
        }   
    } 
?>
```

En donde incluyes tu conexion.

en donde `$state` retorna como boolea.
si aun no resuelve tu duda. te invito a revices la documentacion de [PHP mysql](http://php.net/manual/es/book.mysql.php)
Saludos

Comment: Hola @JuanL gracias por contestar ya revise este método y de igual forma me causa conflicto  en la línea de $gsent =$pdo ->prepare me marca error y ya revise la documentación de PHP mysql pero no encuentro cual es el problema en mi código siendo que el formulario envía bien los datos incluso los imprimo antes pero al momento de insertarlos no los guarda la conexión la tengo bien porque no genera ese error simplemente no los inserta

Comment: @Manuel el `$pdo->prepare` en mi caso es mi variable de instancia genedo en la conexiyon. y `prepare` es exclusivo para PDO, en tu caso es mysqli. indaga un poco mas, verifica primeramente si realmente hay una conexion en tu bd, y si la hay, intenta en hardcodear tu SQL con los datos a ingresar.

Comment: Hola estoy un poco confundido mira el metodo que yo estoy usando es el de (MySQLi Object-oriented) pero si conecta solo que me da este error y la sentencia MYSQL esta bien You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' Ciudad, Estado, Edad, Ocupacion, Correo, TelFijo, Celular, FechaN, FechaUV,) VA' at line 1